# How to fetch emails with Javax using stored hashed passwords?

Tags: passwords, jakarta-mail

Here is my case: six hardware devices send their data to six email addresses (this part is not under my control). I need to retrieve this data in a command-line application. Since I hear everywhere that storing clear-text passwords in a database or in code is bad practice, I would like to ask a user to enter the password for each email once, and store it hashed in a database. I use SSL to encrypt traffic between my application and the mail server.

Therefore, my question is: with these hashed passwords, how do I use Javax to retrieve emails? With clear text, I can do this:

```
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    @Override
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication("USER","PASSWORD");
                    }
                });
```

However, judging from the docs, PasswordAuthentication only works with clear text. What do I do with hashed passwords?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.  If you could, they would be just as good as a clear text password.

You might want to consider [OAuth2 authentication](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/OAuth2), if your server supports it.

Comment: So... what is the proper way for a command line utility like mine to fetch data from an email mailbox? On another subject, I know a little about OAuth, but can it be used in a command line utility?

Comment: It all depends on how paranoid you are.  You can encrypt all the passwords and store them in a database and then ask for the decryption key when you start the CLI.